# Replace all non-alphanumeric characters with AWK

Tags: awk

I know that using `sed -E 's/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]+/?/g $input'` will replace all non-alphanumeric characters of my input file with question mark.

How am I supposed to do the same thing with AWK?

Comment: Check syntax of `gsub`. Same regex will work

Comment: Have it like: `awk '{gsub(/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]+/,"?")} 1' Input_file` where `gsub` denotes Global substitution in `awk`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hey. I've tried that line in my code and it replaces all non-alphanum characters without a space with a single question mark. Like this: Hello!@#$ as Hello?. There's no way to print as "Hello????"

Comment: `awk` and `sed -E` both use EREs. Aside from capture groups a regexp that does something in a POSIX `sed` **will** do the same thing in a POSIX `awk`. Your original `sed` regexp replaces multiple chars with a single `?` and therefore so does the same regexp when used in `awk`. If instead you want each individual char replaced with a `?` then get rid of the `+` from the regexp in both commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix your regex as well as you need to use `awk`'s `gsub` function for your requirement. since we are mentioning `gsub`(global substitution) we need not to use `+` here as it will catch everything at once and will replace everything with a single `?`.

```
awk '{gsub(/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/,"?")} 1' Input_file
```

With input `Hello!@#$` it will become as `Hello????`.

Answer (score 1):

why not `tr`?

```
  ... | tr -c '[:alnum:][:space:]' '?'
```

Comment: It seems like the OP doesn't actually want the `-c`.